# PostgreSQL - check if value is equal to an enum value

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums

I have the following enum declaration:
`CREATE TYPE known_roles_list AS ENUM ('role1', 'role2')`

When the DB executes a certain query, I wish to check if they're doing it with one of these roles, and if not - let the query go through. Something like:

```
IF current_user NOT IN known_roles_list THEN
    RETURN OLD; 
END IF;
```

Obviously, that code above didn't work (raised runtime comparison errors). Nor did `unnest()`-ing the enum values and searching within them.

How can I make that search - and see if *any* of the enum's values match the `current_user` value? (The `current_user` value is just an example - later, I need to compare these enum values to a row value, denoted by column)

Thanks!

Comment: You could use row level security and add a policy on each table.

Comment: Also, use a table rather than an enum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `enum_range(null::known_roles_list)` to get array listing elements of enum and then just use standard array operators. You need to cast that array to `name[]` or it won't be able to compare `name` and `known_roles_list[]`.

```
postgres=> SELECT enum_range(null::known_roles_list);
  enum_range
---------------
 {role1,role2}

postgres=> SELECT current_user;
 current_user
--------------
 lkaminski

postgres=> SELECT current_user = any(enum_range(null::known_roles_list)::name[]);
 ?column?
----------
 f

postgres=> SELECT 'role2'::name = any(enum_range(null::known_roles_list)::name[]);
 ?column?
----------
 t
```

Enum functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-enum.html

Any/Some: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16

Answer (score 4):

Enumerated (`enum`) types are data types, so should be used when creating table structures

```
CREATE TYPE mood AS ENUM ('sad', 'ok', 'happy');
CREATE TABLE person (
    name text,
    current_mood mood
);
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('Moe', 'happy');
SELECT * FROM person WHERE current_mood = 'happy';
```